# How can I show unity UI Slider filling with unitywebrequest downloadProgress for any file type in android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-progressbar, assetbundle, unity-ui, unitywebrequest

(Sorry for bad english)
Hi, I'm using this code for download assetbundle or .mp4 files via unitywebrequest :

```
public IEnumerator Download (List<string> urls) {

        for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++) {
            
            string ext = Path.GetExtension (urls[i]);
            
            if (ext == ".mp4") {
                 uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get (urls[i]);
            }
            if(ext == ".unity3d") {
                 uwr = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(urls[i]);
            }
            
            
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName (urls[i]);
            
            string path = Path.Combine (myFolder + "/" + fileName);
            uwr.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerFile (path);
            
            
            StartCoroutine (ShowDownloadProgress (uwr)); // Progress Bar With Unity Slider
            
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest ();
            
            if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError) {
                print ("Error");
            }
            else {
                print ("File successfully downloaded and saved to " + path);
            }           
        }
}
```

And using this code to show download progress with unity slider:

```
public IEnumerator ShowDownloadProgress (UnityWebRequest www) {
    while (!www.isDone) {
        downloadProgressSlider.value = www.downloadProgress;
        downloadProgressTxt.text = (string.Format ("{0:0%}", www.downloadProgress));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (.01f);
    }
    downloadProgressSlider.value = 0;
}
```

Everything is fine in unity editor when code downloading any file type and I can see slider value change and fill it:

[image]

But my export .apk has different result, it show filling slider only when application downloading .mp4 files, but for another file type like .xml,.unity3d or etc. value skip to end for each file!